# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list using .css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I try to set the height of a div equalvalent to its width using .width() but I got an error of

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

here's my js

```
$('#myDiv').css('height':($('#myDiv').width()));
```

Comment: You put an extra pair of parentheses around `$('#myDiv').width()`. Also, the colon in the middle has to be a comma.

Comment: I want to add. Whenever you see `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` -- This means you either forgot a `)` or have too many `(`s on that line. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have syntax error in your code.

if you want set one item you can use this:

```
$('#myDiv').css('height',$('#myDiv').width());
```

if you want to set multiple item you can use this:

```
$('#myDiv').css({'height':$('#myDiv').width()});
```

for more info you can check [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: The first one is used when adding one single property to the CSS. Second one is used when adding multiple CSS properties, separated by commas.

Comment: I would recommend adding explanations to this, even if it is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have a pretty normal error. All you have to do is reformat your code to:

```
$('#myDiv').css('height',$('#myDiv').width());
```

Just remove the colon and extra parentheses!